# Fire an action after a NSTextField is modified in a Cell based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

i have a problem, i want to fire an action after a NSTextField in the 4th column in my tableview is edited (when the users press enter or tab). I have difficulties implementing this solution. Some developers suggested me to look up the NSTableViewDelegate documentation from apple but i don't see how i can use it. Some suggested me to use a combination of doubleAction, clickedRow and clickedColumn, but i don't see how i could use it. I'm really lost. I first thought that by using controlTextDidEndEditing this would work, but it doesn't work. Can someone explain me in a simple way how to fire an action once the user have finished a Cell (NSTextField) in a cell based NSTableView? If you have an example, this would be great, i.e. write a simple Log message once the user has finished editing a cell.

Thank you

Comment: You can't have a `NSTextField` in a cell based `NSTableView`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Willeke but it's what is written, when i create an outlet it's a NSTextField i was surprised myself. The content mode is Cell based i verified it in the attribute inspector

Comment: an outlet of a text cell*

Comment: The text cell of the table column isn't a `NSTextField`. In a cell based table view `controlTextDidEndEditing:` should work. Did you connect the delegate?

Comment: Ok, my bad. How do i connect the delegate? What should i connect to? My tableview is already connected to ViewController, the file owner :tableView.delegate = self

Comment: You can connect the delegate in the xib/storyboard or set the delegate in code.

Comment: So let me get this straight: I connect the action of the text field to the delegate of the table view in the storyboard/xib file? Is it right? I'm sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: Don't use the action. Connect or set the delegate of the table view. Implement `controlTextDidEndEditing:` in the delegate class.

Comment: thank you Willeke you made my day!